# Does parsley.js support type="number" fields that have leading zeros, like zip code?

Tags: parsley.js

We have a zip code field. Right now we have it as type="text", but that means that phones don't use the numeric keypad.  But before, when we had it as a type="number" the leading zeros would disappear - I think because of Parsley.js. Does this sound right? Is there a parsley.js option that allows us to use the number type without removing leading zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because of Parsley, it's because of the spec.

Use `type=tel` and `pattern="-?\d+"`

Comment: Uh...  As I said in the question, then the phone doesn't get the numeric keypad.

Comment: Oops, indeed, sorry. You're right, `type=tel` sounds much better :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am using type="tel" plus a pattern.